# Is it necessary to use hibernate-spatial for postgis?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, point, hibernate-spatial

I'm beginner in GIS. I have a database in PostgreSQL that contains a table location, that table contains a column with type point. I have to get points and display it on google map. Once I did the mapping with Hibernate, it gave me for the column point the type Serializable as follow:

```
<property name="point" type="serializable">
        <column name="point" />
```

I really don't understand why it gave me serializable for that column. Is it necessary to use hibernate-spatial for that case? What can I do? I've searched a lot but I still don't know if it is necessary to use spatial hibernate knowing that I don't have much stuffs related to GIS to use for my application.

Comment: You are using hibernate for the rest of the application?